# Existence of smaller measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the measure $\mu$ on $R$ such that $\mu([-r,r])>0$ for all $r> 0$.

Can we construct a (smooth) function $f$ satisfying $\mu -fdx\geq 0$ in a measure sense?
If $\mu$ has a continuous density $g$, then it seems easy. But what conditions are needed for the existence of $f$ for a measure $\mu$? or is it possible always?

Comment: What's wrong with $f=0$?

Comment: I wish that f is not trivial

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want $f$ to be a non-negative smooth function.

If $(r_n)$ is an evaluation of rational numbers and $\mu =\sum \frac 1 {2^{n}} \delta_{r_n}$ then the only function $f$ satsfying your conditioin is $f=0$ (up to a Lebesgue null set). This becasue $\int_E f(x)dx\leq m(E)=0$ for any Borel set $E$ contained in $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ and this implies $\int_E f =0$ for all  Borel sets $E$.

Note: If a smooth function is $0$ a.e. [Lebesgue] then it is $0$ at every point.

The same conclusin holds for any $\mu$ singualr w.r.t. Lebesgue measure. If $\mu$ is concentared on $S$ and $m$ (Lebesgue measure) on it complement then $\mu (E) \geq \int_Ef=0$ for all $E$ in side $S^{c}$ and $\int_E f(x)xd=0$ for $E$ inside $S$ also. So $f=0$ a.e. [Lebesgue].

Comment: Thank you for a concrete example! Then, can we add some conditions on $\mu$ to get a nontrivial $f$? For example, non-atomic $\mu$.

Comment: My argument works for any $\mu$ singular w.r.t. Lebesgue measure.  @JaeyunYi

Comment: Would you explain more for the extension?: for any singular $\mu$, $f$ should be zero?

Comment: @JaeyunYi I have edited.